# if it exist the limit of $f(z_n)$ then there exist the the limit of $z_n$

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis

Let $D \subset \mathbb{C}$ a closed compact subset of the complex plane.

Let $f:D \to \mathbb{C}$ a continuous function.

Let $\{z_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \in D$ a sequence of $D$.

Is it true that
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} f(z_n)=L \Longrightarrow \lim_{n \to \infty} z_n = z_0 \in D
$$

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whenever you have a question like this, try it with some simple examples. The very simplest continuous function is a constant function. Does that answer your question?

Comment: yes, you answered, thanks

Answer (score 2):

No.  Take $f$ a constant function and $\{z_n\}$ any divergent sequence.

Comment: $D$ is compact so $z_n$ connot diverge

Comment: "Divergent" can mean "non-convergent" as well as "divergent to $\infty$".

Comment: ok, thanks @PatrickStevens